# Unable to connect error in the csf update

Tags: linux, server, centos, firewall

If you refer to the ConfigServer Security & Firewall - csf on your server, in "Upgrade" section you should see this message: 

*"You are running the latest version of csf. An Upgrade button will appear here if a new version becomes available"*

One of the features of this firewall is its automatic update, if a new version of the CSF firewall is available, the CSF will automatically update it to the new version.

The user sent us a CSF update report and, in the explanations for us, the error is

*"Unable to connect to https://download.configserver.com, retry in 300 seconds."*

**which we will continue to teach you how to fix this problem**.

Note: This training is tested on the operating system centos 6.7

This error is due to the non-installation of Crypt-SSLeay on the server, so you must have access to the server management, you can use the putty software to log onto your ssh server and install yum by this package. After entering ssh, enter the following command on the server:

```
# yum install perl-Crypt-SSLeay
```

Wait for 5 minutes and try again if your problem still exists,

in "csf - ConfigServer Firewall" Section,click on "Firewall Configuration" buttom, then find "URLGET" and set it to "2", go to end of the page and click on "Change" buttom,then restart CSF.

If you see this Warning:

*"URLGET set to use LWP but perl module is not installed"*

This problem is due to the fact that Perl's required modules are not installed on the server. Some CSF firewall operations depend on the modules and packages installed in the CSF, which does not work properly if these CSF modules or packages are not installed. To fix this error, you must install perl-libwww-perl packages and net-tools and perl-LWP-protocol-https on your Linux operating system. To install these packages, you must connect to the SSH server, then log in to the server administration and enter the following command:

```
# yum install perl-libwww-perl net-tools perl-LWP-Protocol-https
```

**Your Problem Solved. Good luck :)**

for update CSF on Command line use:

```
# csf -u
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem upgrading to CSF version 13.05! The problem that I have found was the Country Block did not take note but I guess the update server is located in NL? Remove all country block restart CSF and do the

```
# csf -u  using shell
```

et voilà!